# Passing String Variable as Parameter in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an AJAX request that returns the following text and assigns it to a JavaScript variable called `authCodes`. 
Text from AJAX request: `value === '1' || value === '2' || value === '3'`.

The following code works with the text manually inserted.

```
$.validator.addMethod("authCode", function(value, element, param) { 
return this.optional(element) || (value === '1' || value === '2' || value === '3'); 
}, "Please enter a valid access code.");
```

However, when I try to put the variable `authCodes` in, the function does not work. Here is it with the variable inserted instead of manually.

```
$.validator.addMethod("authCode", function(value, element, param) { 
return this.optional(element) || (authCodes); 
}, "Please enter a valid access code.");
```

This code is related to form validation and it seems that with the second method, the contents of the text input are ignored and lets any value through. Whereas with the first method, only the values of 1, 2, and 3 are let through.

Any help is appreciated and thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: can you change the AJAX response?

Comment: I am retrieving these values from a database and putting them into this format, so manual updates are not necessary to the validation function. 
Change the AJAX response to what/how? @k-nut

Comment: In your first version `value==='1'` refers to the `value` passed into the function. Are you sure the when `authCodes` is assigned the value isn't `"value === '1' || value === '2' || value === '3'"`?

Comment: where is authCodes defined? possibly the addMethod returns the value of authCodes

Comment: You're not *evaluating* the expression contained in `authCodes` variable, but simply checking its value. You can use `eval` to do it, but the whole approach seems very odd to me. Usually, when you're reaching the server you expect to get **data** in return, not **behavior**.

Comment: do you only ever want to compare the `values` variable? Then you should just return a json with the values that are allowed and check if the value is in the list

Answer (score 0):

To execute a javascript code from a string, you have to use the [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function :

```
$.validator.addMethod("authCode", function(value, element, param) { 
return this.optional(element) || eval(authCodes); 
}, "Please enter a valid access code.");
```

Be warned, the use of this function is dangerous and allowed anyone to execute any batch of code. It is preferable to get a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing to a string here. If you actually want to execute the code that you get from your ajax reply you could use javascripts's `eval`. Beware that this can get very dangerous though because your code will just be executed. But changing it to this will work:

```
$.validator.addMethod("authCode", function(value, element, param) { 
return this.optional(element) || eval(authCodes); 
}, "Please enter a valid access code.");
```

It would be much better to get a list of acceptable values and then just check if the value that you have is in this list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a string from an AJAX response and expect javascript to treat it like code. It's treating it like a string, because that's what it is. Your second bit of code actually looks like this when it evaluates, I expect:

```
$.validator.addMethod("authCode", function(value, element, param) { 
return this.optional(element) || ("value === '1' || value === '2' || value === '3'"); 
}, "Please enter a valid access code.");
```

And javascript will treat that non-empty string as "truthy" and evaluate it to true. The above answers do suggest using `eval()` which would probably work but is super-dangerous, and I would not recommend it.

What I expect you want is for your AJAX to return an array of values like ['1','2','3'] and then check whether the value is in the array.

Comment: I disagree with your first affirmation, javascript can treat string like code, indeed it's very dangerous.

Comment: That's true, you can treat a string like code with eval(), but you need to use a function to make javascript evaluate a string like code. It won't do it automatically, which is what OP was expecting. And you shouldn't do things that way, in any case! :)

Comment: Disagree again, you can use it in a non dangerous way, like in an anonymous function, you need to exec a function named with appended text from variable checked by a fixed list. Eval in javascript is less dangerous than in PHP, in javascript anything can be rewritten or executed.